# Highlighting the active tab item in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created tabs using `<ion-tabs>`. Every thing was working fine but i am not able to change the active tab background color.

```
 <ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-positive">
            <ion-tab id="personalDetails" title="Personal" href="#/newcustomer/PersonalDetails" ng-class="{{createUserStatus.personaldetails == true ? 'activeTab': ''}}">
                <ion-nav-view name="newcustomer-PersonalDetails"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>
            <ion-tab id="familyDetails" title="Family &amp; Housing" href="#/newcustomer/FamilyDetails" disabled="true" ng-class="{{createUserStatus.personaldetails == true ? 'activeTab': ''}}">
                <ion-nav-view name="newcustomer-FamilyDetails"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
```

I tried using the css, but not working

```
.activeTab a.tab-item{
  background: red !important;
}
```

Firebug is looking like this,

[image]

I need to apply css for  tag. how do i apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the Ionic CSS class *.tab-item.tab-item-active*, so for example add into your custom .css file:

```
.tab-item.tab-item-active, .tab-item.active, .tab-item.activated {
    opacity: 1;
    background: red;
}
```